# Can I abandon my own faction in M&B: Warband? (PoP 3)

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband, mount-and-blade

I've founded a new kingdom and realised there are still things I want to do before starting a big campaign - I can't for now help claimants or join somebody as mercenary. But i don't see there any "leave kingdom" button nor any other way :(. If I just lose all my fiefs, faction still exists. I'm playing Prophesy of Pendor 3, but I'm not sure if there's any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the unmodded game, you can still rejoin a different faction or support a claimant in order to end your current faction. However, there isn't a way to return to being unaffiliated. You probably just need to make peace and raise your standing with one faction until they offer you the chance to become a mercenary again.

Comment: Yea that's basically it. just play nice and make friends with somebody, and when you join them they will take over your land, however, correct me if i'm wrong but i think i remember when you join another faction like this you keep all your old fiefs just under the new factions flag.

Comment: Yes, you do keep old fiefs.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask a king to let you be his vassal then you will join his kingdom. Then ask he to release you from your oath (which he will do for a relation debuff) after that you will lose your holdings but you will be free from any responsibility to the king and your faction will be gone.